# Using Flow within process builder to create UserPackageLicense Records

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, flow

I have designed a ***Autolaunched Flow*** which creates **UserPackageLicense** record in order to assign License for a managed package to a user.

Now I have designed a process on USER object on create/edit(No criteria), which will trigger the Autolaunched Flow as an **immediate action** which will create **UserPackageLicense** record which results in assigning the license to the user Automatically.

> In Order to Create the UserPackageLicense there are 2 required field
>   we need to populate. 1.UserId 2.PackageLicenseId

**UserId**

> I am passing User Id from prcoess -to-> Flow variable and I am using
>   that variable in flow to create **UserPackageLicense** record.

**PackageLicenseId**

> For **PackageLicenseId** I am using Lookup in flow which will find the
>   **PackageLicenseId** based on predefined Namespace Prefix of Package and I am using that id value as UserPackageLicense

But on update of user record I am receiving this error : "
Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301P***********. Contact your administrator for help. "

The same Flow & Process works perfectly for **Account** object instead of **UserPackageLicense**

> I have also tried to create a process by using Scheduled actions
>   instead of **Immediate Action** as given [here](https://automationchampion.com/2015/09/06/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-43-auto-assign-package-license-to-new-user/) .

Comment: is flow working itself? Standalone, without trigger/PB?

Answer (score 0):

From the Help, you may want to read [Workflow for the User Object (Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_user_object_limitations.htm&language=th) and along with the product manager's comments on [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br80AAC) which is considered delivered. In essence, for security reasons, what you can do via workflow on the User object is limited. Process Builder is essentially workflow. I recommend you move what you're doing into to a trigger.